# Light Ray in AdS

Tags: geodesics, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

On p77 of these lecture notes (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0712.0689v2.pdf), we are asked to check that a light ray takes infinitely long to reach the centre of AdS.

1, Why doesn't the Penrose diagram for null rays (which travel at 45 degrees bouncing off +infinity at one side and then -infinity at the other) rule this out?

2, Solving the geodesic equation $ds^2=0$ for null rays in global coordinates gives my $\rho(t)=\pm t$ which would support my above statement, surely? I understand that this is coordinate time but e.g. if I have an observer at rest at $\rho_0$, his proper time will equal the coordinate time and so surely he would agree that the light ray reached $\rho=0$ in finite proper/coordinate time?

3, On page 169 of his [book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nfdfCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=nastase+good+chance+for+the+theory+to+be+holographic&source=bl&ots=WsYZ7eBe63&sig=T_PQ_LTn3U60Eao4tLx8JJ6Bz90&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6gIa-_JTKAhWJRhQKHat2AF0Q6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=nastase%20good%20chance%20for%20the%20theory%20to%20be%20holographic&f=false), the same author shows that what we really want to calculate is $\int e^{-y} dy$. I'm not sure what coordinates he's using here but he says in the original question that we should be able to see this using global coordinates as well....